# Mongo assigning same ObjectId? MongoError: E11000 duplicate key error collection

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I'm trying to insert new documents in a collection, but after the first one (when I'm trying to insert the second one) mongo shows me the following error:

```
 MongoError: E11000 duplicate key error collection: bbdd.productions index: _id_ dup key: { : ObjectId('5b118dabefd04e51a28ffc4d') }
```

Actually it makes sense, because "_id" : ObjectId("5b118dabefd04e51a28ffc4d") is the id that was assigned to the first document inserted.

I read that maybe there are indexes causing the problem, but that collection only has the *id* index.

db.productions.getIndexes() shows:

```
[
    {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "_id" : 1
        },
        "name" : "_id_",
        "ns" : "production_rapipizza.productions"
    }
]
```

I tried removing with .dropIndexes() and restarting the app but it didn't work (I'm getting the same error when I'm creating new documents of that collection).

I think that mongo is assigning the same ObjectId to the first document and the following, but.. it's not possible, is it?

model:

```
    model.Production = mongoose.model("productions", new Schema({
    products: {type: Array, required: true},
    date: {type: Date, required: true},
    user: {type: ObjectId, ref: 'users', required: true},
    createdAt: {type: Date, default: Date.now}
}, {collection: 'productions', timestamps: true}));
```

My query in node:

```
    app.post('/api/production', (req, res, next) => {
    req.body.date = new Date(req.body.date);
    const production = new model.Production(req.body);
    return production.save().then(
        () => res.status(200).send("La producción para el día indicado fue registrado exitosamente"))
        .catch(next)
});
```

if I do the equivalent through the mongodb shell it works correctly, so I think that i'm doing wrong the above code. This is what I call "equivalent":

```
db.productions.insert({products: [ { "product" : "oneproduct", quantity : 100 } ], date : ISODate("2018-06-03T03:00:00Z"), user : ObjectId("5b0b50326b351b4527b067c6")});
```

My first document inserted:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5b118dabefd04e51a28ffc4d"), "products" : [ { "product" : "nameoftheproduct", "quantity" : "100" } ], "date" : ISODate("2018-06-01T03:00:00Z"), "user" : ObjectId("5b0b50326b351b4527b067c6"), "createdAt" : ISODate("2018-06-01T18:17:15.404Z"), "updatedAt" : ISODate("2018-06-01T18:17:15.404Z"), "__v" : 0 }
```

Any help or ideas will be gratefully received.

Comment: post your query and document you do insert

Comment: Done. Thanks for your reply

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the same component for save and edit. So if at the beginning I select any production recorded and then tried to create a new one, it kept the _id of the first one. I needed to clear the _id in the react state.